# Positioning input-group-addon on top of text-input

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to finish simple form, but I'm loosing my mind dealing with CSS, etc. Here is a picture that shows what is wrong

[image]

As you can see, Label is position like 1px to the left and button is bigger than input. I'v used same `input-group-addon` with textarea, using this style

```
    .input-group{
width: 100%;
}
    .input-group-addon{
width: 220px !important;
}
    .textarea-addon{
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px !important;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px !important;
  border:1px solid #ccc !important;
  border-bottom: none !important;
}
```

And it works perfect, but using it with text input just looks ugly. Here is the code

```
 <div class="col-sm-12">
    <span class="input-group-addon textarea-addon">Account numbers</span>    
    <div class="input-group input-group-sm form-inline panel">                                                
        <input type="text" ng-model="model.accountNumber" id ="accountNumber" class="form-control" style="width:80%"> </input>                                                
        <input type="button" ng-click="add(accountNumber)" value="Add" class="btn btn" style="width:20%"></input>                                                                                                   
    </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will helpful for you, I have put new class to your code

```
.inputgroup_flex {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
    border-width: 0;
}
.inputgroup_flex #accountNumber {
    height: 36px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/Thakur92411/pen/QZLqNZ